# stop mysql daemon container from docker

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I have been working on getting mysql docker image inside my windos 10 local machine . It works well , but the problem is that I delete the .yml file ( I also run docker with command to sepcific file ) . Now in each time I run docker , I got adminer container that won't to be deleted at all . suggesstions please ?

deleteing docker and reinstall
forcing container to delete , but in few seconds one other appear

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

during docker mysql configuration , I got command that have docker swarm . Past it without reading about .
I just stoped the swarm service .

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).